# Firebase get key for the last inserted item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database reference.

```
houseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("House");
```

I add an item to the db using:

```
houseReference.push().setValue(house);
```

Google firebase reference documentation [says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getKey()) you can then get the key for the last item using

```
houseReference.getKey();
```

However, this returns `House`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase has no concept of "the last key". But each `DatabaseReference` is a reference to a path in the database, and you get the last key in that path by calling `getKey()` on it. So if you call `houseReference.getKey()` you indeed get `house`, since that is the last key in the path that it refers to.

Now we get to the good stuff though.

When you call `push()` Firebase generates (in the client) a new unique key, and return a new `DatabaseReference` that point to that key under the current path. So `houseReference.push()` returns a new `DatabaseReference` to the new, unique, child location. And this means that you can call `getKey()` on this new `DatabaseReference` to get the last key of that new location.

So:

```
DatabaseReference newRef = houseReference.push();
System.out.println(newRef.getKey());
newRef.setValue(house);
```

Comment: My problem was that I wasn't storing this new reference. Puf always there for Firebase, thanks one more time.